# How to properly animate an object in Angular using the [hidden] property?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm new to Angular (9). I've just learnt I cannot use the `*ngIf` directive in some cases: for example when using bootstrap's tooltips (which use popper.js) for reasons I don't understand yet.

I know I could use the `[hidden]` property instead of `*ngIf` on the parent container, and in this case tooltips would work.

However, by doing so, I would loose the easy to use `:enter` and `:leave` aliases used in the animations. The current code looks like this :

`ngif_directive_component.html`:

```
<div @grow *ngIf="showCard" class="card">
some content
</div>
```

`ngif_directive_component.ts`:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('grow',[
      transition(':enter', [
        animate('500ms', keyframes([
          style({ height: '0', opacity: 0 }),
          style({ height: '*', opacity: 0 }),
          style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 }),
        ]))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('500ms', keyframes([
        style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 }),
        style({ height: '*', opacity: 0 }),
        style({ height: '0', opacity: 0 }),
      ]))
  ])
  ])]
```

If I replace the `*ngIf` directive like so :

```
<div @grow [hidden]="showCard" class="card">
some content
</div>
```

Of course the animations would not work anymore.

I've tried to do this

```
<div [@grow]="showCard" [hidden]="showCard" class="card">
some content
</div>
```

```
  animations: [
    trigger('grow',[
      transition('false => true', [
        animate('500ms', keyframes([
          style({ height: '0', opacity: 0 }),
          style({ height: '*', opacity: 0 }),
          style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 }),
        ]))
    ]),
    transition('true => false', [
      animate('500ms', keyframes([
        style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 }),
        style({ height: '*', opacity: 0 }),
        style({ height: '0', opacity: 0 }),
      ]))
  ])
  ])]
```

But in this case the *hide* animation does not work anymore. I suppose the card is hidden before the animation is done. So how to make both animations work?